# I have python 3.7.3 in my old laptop, I installed python 3.8 on my new laptop and it's not working anymore

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, module

I know very little regarding python,I'm using it to get data from twitter.

my old laptop has python version 3.7.3 it works fine, but I didn't set it up.

I installed python on my new laptop, but I think I also need to install some packages from my old python (laptop)

the error shows in my new laptop "no module named twitter"

I don't know how this works.

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/

Answer (score 2):

If you use newly installed python on new laptop cannot get or copy the modules from old laptop. You want to install the modules you need.

```
pip install twitter
```

Use this on command prompt to download the twitter packages.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have installed a new version consider it as a new environment and all the dependency related to the project will be missing. So in order to have all the plugins and software installed in the new environment you run few commands in your old environment (in your case it is old laptop).

```
$pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

here you will get text file which will contain all the dependencies required in your project. So just take this file and paste it in new environment (new laptop) and then run the following command.

```
$pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This will install the packages required in your project instead of installing individually.

Comment: I will try this and I will update you on what happened. Thank you so much.

Comment: When I tried.   $pip freeze > requirements.txt     it showed    command not found: freeze

Comment: try pip list> requirements.txt

Comment: Bro u are running this command outside python environment so first of all make python accessible globally by setting environment variable in windows and then try to run this commands

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to cd to your python project and then activate your virtual environment and run
`pip install twitter`

Comment: cd to where the python folder is located or to the python script?

Comment: where your project is located